# Pandas dataframe detect patterns in the data (duplicates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to detect patterns in the values of keyword column.

Patterns such as:
"kw1, kw2, kw3",
"kw1, kw4, kw5",
"kw6, kw7" 
etc...

Pattern definition:

- Several keywords in consecutive rows (this will already be the case)
- Keywords all "belong" to one
  URL.
- As soon as there is a duplicate in the keywords pattern is
  interrupted and a new pattern starts.

```
URL    Keyword  Patterns

url1   kw1       Pattern1   
url1   kw2       Pattern1
url1   kw3       Pattern1
url1   kw1       Pattern2   (beginning new pattern because kw1 appears for the second time)
url1   kw4       Pattern2
url1   kw5       Pattern2
url2   kw6       Pattern3   (beginning new pattern because url2)
url2   kw7       Pattern3   
url3   kw8       Pattern4   
url3   kw9       Pattern4   
url3   kw10      Pattern4
```

What I need is the code that would fill in column "Patterns"

Comment: please be more specific what a pattern looks like. is it the same value? you can ```groupby``` for that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data frame is sorted as in your example, you could use Boolean series like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['url1', 'url1', 'url1', 'url1', 'url1', 'url1', 
                           'url2', 'url2', 'url3', 'url3', 'url3'], 
                   'keyword': ['kw01', 'kw02', 'kw03', 'kw01', 'kw04', 'kw05', 
                               'kw06', 'kw07', 'kw08', 'kw09', 'kw10']})

# add a Boolean column to the data frame that is True iff 
# the URL is different from the previous one
df['new_url'] = df.URL != df.URL.shift() 

# add a Boolean column to the data frame that is True iff 
# the keyword comes before the previous keyword in alphanumerical order
df['old_keyword'] = df.keyword < df.keyword.shift()

# add a Boolean column to the data frame that is True iff 
# at least one of the previous two columns is True
df['new_pattern'] = df[['new_url', 'old_keyword']].any(axis='columns')

# cumulatively sum up the number of True values in the previous column
df['pattern'] = df['new_pattern'].cumsum()

df
```

```py
    URL     keyword     new_url     old_keyword     new_pattern  pattern
0   url1    kw01        True        False           True         1
1   url1    kw02        False       False           False        1
2   url1    kw03        False       False           False        1
3   url1    kw01        False       True            True         2
4   url1    kw04        False       False           False        2
5   url1    kw05        False       False           False        2
6   url2    kw06        True        False           True         3
7   url2    kw07        False       False           False        3
8   url3    kw08        True        False           True         4
9   url3    kw09        False       False           False        4
10  url3    kw10        False       False           False        4
```

As you have noted, this approach relies on alphanumerical ordering of the keywords for the creation of the `old_keyword` column. So it won't work as is for e.g. keywords `99x` and `100x`. To fix that, you could format your keyword column in either of two ways:

1. Fill up the numbers with zeros to the left so that all the keyword strings have the same length;
2. Extract the numbers from the keyword strings and convert them to integer.

Comment: it works quite well. Do you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: btw, it seems that it only works if keywords contain numbers? And for some reason it only works when the numbers in my keyword are < 10. (My keyword are mostly under the format "digit. text")

Comment: @user1564140 I added some explanations to my answer.